# Understanding Functional Interface Methods and Method References

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

I want to go with definitions and their examples.

```
@FunctionalInterface public class Supplier<T> {
   public T get();
}
```

Its usage is

```
Supplier<LocalDate> s1 = LocalDate::now;
Supplier<LocalDate> s2 = () -> LocalDate.now();
LocalDate d1 = s1.get();
LocalDate d2 = s2.get();
```

Here, my comprehension is `now` is factory method and referred to by `s1` and `s2`. Their types are `Supplier<LocalDate>`. I get from the type *`LocalDate::now`* returns `LocalDate` type.

```
@FunctionalInterface public class Consumer<T> {
   void accept(T t);
}
```

Its usage,

```
Consumer<String> c1 = System.out::println;
Consumer<String> c2 = x -> System.out.println(x);
```

`println` is the method taking String, returning nothing.

Lastly,

```
@FunctionalInterface public class Predicate<T> {
   boolean test(T t);
}
@FunctionalInterface public class BiPredicate<T, U> {
   boolean test(T t, U u);
}
```

Their usages,

```
Predicate<String> p1 = String::isEmpty;
Predicate<String> p2 = x -> x.isEmpty();

BiPredicate<String, String> b1 = String::startsWith;
BiPredicate<String, String> b2 = (string, prefix) -> string.startsWith(prefix);
```

My problem is here that `Predicate` has a method declaration returning `boolean` and passing nothing. Doesn't it? In the above two examples at left-hand side among diamond operators there are types either return type or passing type. So, `isEmpty` declaration has no type for passing, `boolean` for returning. Same act applies for `BiPredicate` that `startsWith` takes just only one parameter type of `String`, returns boolean. How does it work? Because I think it should work with `Predicate` not with `BiPredicate`. But, in this case `isEmpty` shouldn't work with `Predicate` but works. I'm a little confused. Would you explain it?

Comment: The example code in your question is essentially showing the answer. The instance method reference is treated as if the 0th argument is the instance itself. For example `String::isEmpty` is essentially equivalent to `x -> x.isEmpty()`.

Comment: For non-static methods the first Parameter given will be the Object on which the method should be called

Comment: @Radiodef This question should not be marked as a duplicate ! I think you misunderstood what the OP asked.

Comment: I think so it shouldn't be marked as duplication. @Radiodef I think your reply is not really what op expects. He/she is certainly cognizant of it. **If you really know it, explain well please. If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough.** And I think you can't

Comment: That is a strong dup for this actually. it's not referring to the same interfaces but it answers the same question. OP seems to be confusing what the type declaration is declaring.